# Gradle error on eclipse 2020-12 : Task:compileJava FAILED Unrecognized option : -h

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

When I lunch my  Gradle build scripts I get the following error:

`Task:compileJava FAILED Unrecognized option : -h`.

I tried to fix that by setting up eclipse to use a specific Gradle Version

[image]

Yet when I do that  my Gradle tasks fail to load altogether

Please note that the build used to go through  on the former version of eclipse, yet I had to use the latest version since I updated my OS to  Mac Big Sur

Comment: That's been a common Gradle warning since Gradle 4 at least. It's not an error, it's merely stating that, once you start using Gradle 7, some of the features you're using are deprecated. It shouldn't stop you from building with Gradle 5.6

Comment: @afterburner  true ,   i edited the question , the error i am getting is  Task :compileJava FAILED
Unrecognized option : -h

Comment: Do you also get that error when using the command line? Furthermore, do you have any custom tasks or invocations that are trying to pass a `-h` flag?

Comment: @afterburner i get the same error from the commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding

```
options.headerOutputDirectory.convention(null)
```

to `compileJava` Gradle task